# Вылетает игра при попытке сменить дизайн плащя в LemonGUI

Tags: java, minecraft

и так, у меня есть

```
public Cape()
    {
        super("Cape", "Wow! this is cape", Category.COSMETICS, Keyboard.KEY_NONE);
        ArrayList<String> capedesign = new ArrayList<>();
        capedesign.add("Hentai");
        capedesign.add("Amazon");
        capedesign.add("Future");
        capedesign.add("Kamiblue");
        capedesign.add("Retro");
        Serverexe.setmgr.rSetting(new Setting("CapeDesign", this, "Hentai", capedesign));
    }
```

этот код добавляет дизайн плащя, который можно сменить, но при попытке смены вылетает игра, как пофиксить? [вот видео](https://cdn.upload.systems/uploads/mPMAofvk.mp4), а [вот лог](https://pastebin.com/82uCxHJy)

Comment: может покажете лог падения?

Comment: А, хорошо, сейчас https://pastebin.com/82uCxHJy

Comment: приложите пожалуйста в тело вопроса данный лог

Comment: @Andrew,  обновил